# Separating styles into different CSS files from a single Stylus source file

Tags: css, internet-explorer, conditional-statements, stylesheet, stylus

I've been using this technique to create IE conditional stylesheets during development:

http://clock.co.uk/blog/handling-ie-with-stylus

Basically it allows me to write IE specific CSS alongside non-IE styles and it will automatically split it in a new file.  For the most part it's been great but if I were to change one thing about it is that it creates 2 full copies of the CSS files,  just one copy contains extra IE-specific styles as well.  What I would like to do is have only the IE specific styles appear in the separate file.

So if I do something like this in Stylus

```
/* styles.styl */
.myDiv 
  +ie(8)
    width: 100px
  background: #000
  color: red

.other
  display: block
  width: 10px
```

I want the 2 files to look like this:

```
/* styles.css: */
.myDiv {
  background: #000;
  color: red;
 }

.other {
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
}

/* styles-ie8.css: Just the IE specific styles */
.myDiv {
  width: 100px;
}
```

instead of styles-ie.css ending up like this:

```
/* styles-ie8.css: */
.myDiv {
  width: 100px; /* <-- includes the extra IE-specific style along with everything else */
  background: #000;
  color: red;
}

.other {
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
}
```

Just curious if this is possible, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible without wrapping the rest of your Stylus in `+not-ie()` style mixins (obviously not recommended), or extending Stylus somehow.

At Clock we faced the same problem – aiming to serve one stylesheet to every browser, with just the extras going to IE8 in a separate stylesheet. Unfortunately we couldn't find a decent way to handle this.

What we do currently is, as you mention, have a complete copy of the styles in the IE8 stylesheet, along with the IE8 specific styles. The advantage of this is that we now only need to send one stylesheet to IE8 Users, saving them an HTTP request when compared to the above method.

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
link(rel='stylesheet', href='index.css')
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
link(rel='stylesheet', href='index-ie8.css')
<![endif]-->
```

Good browsers, including IE9+ get `index.css` only. IE8 and lower get `index-ie8.css` only. No browser gets the same styles twice.

Afraid it's not the solution you're looking for, but at least it's a bit of reasoning behind our decisions.

Comment: thanks for your response.  I figured that it wasn't possible without possibly extending Stylus.  I even thought about writing my own extension for it but it's a lot more involved then your simple extension.  I guess I'll just stick to using the same thing I was doing (which is what you are doing too)